# How to use OwlExporter in GATE embedded

Tags: nlp, owl, gate

I have [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/family/embedded.html) pipeline having PR (Processing Resources) and LR (Language Resources), but don't know how to add [OwlExporter](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/owlexporter) plugin. I have OwlExporter folder downloaded but no idea how to add it. I have done entity extraction for Person, Place, Organisation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't know what exactly? Have you read the [documentation](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/system/files/owlexporter-3.2.pdf)? I mean, everything is there, also the installation (p. 4 ff )